# print.xtable messing up html tags

Tags: html, r, html-table, xtable

I face difficulties using `print.xtable` to insert a html table inside another table.

```
DF=data.frame(A=c("a","b"),B=c("This is a text
<table border=1>
<tr> <th>  </th> <th> x </th> <th> error </th>  </tr>
  <tr> <td align=\"right\"> 1 </td> <td> element1 </td> <td> thing1 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td align=\"right\"> 2 </td> <td> element2 </td> <td> thing2 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td align=\"right\"> 3 </td> <td> element3 </td> <td> thing3 </td> </tr>
   </table>","ok"))
```

This seems to work fine: (the html tags of the inner table are similar to the html tags of the outer table)

```
xtable(DF,digits=2)
```

but `print.xtable(xtable(DF,digits=2), type="html")` is converting the inner table tags to `&lt;` and `&gt;` :

```
<!-- html table generated in R 3.1.2 by xtable 1.7-4 package -->
<!-- Mon Feb 16 05:55:32 2015 -->
<table border=1>
<tr> <th>  </th> <th> A </th> <th> B </th>  </tr>
  <tr> <td align="right"> 1 </td> <td> a </td> <td> This is a text
&lt;table border=1&gt;
&lt;tr&gt; &lt;th&gt;  &lt;/th&gt; &lt;th&gt; x &lt;/th&gt; &lt;th&gt; error &lt;/th&gt;  &lt;/tr&gt;
  &lt;tr&gt; &lt;td align="right"&gt; 1 &lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt; element1 &lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt; thing1 &lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt;
  &lt;tr&gt; &lt;td align="right"&gt; 2 &lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt; element2 &lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt; thing2 &lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt;
  &lt;tr&gt; &lt;td align="right"&gt; 3 &lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt; element3 &lt;/td&gt; &lt;td&gt; thing3 &lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt;
   &lt;/table&gt; </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td align="right"> 2 </td> <td> b </td> <td> ok </td> </tr>
   </table>
```

hence my question: is there a way to make sure all tags are kept intacts?

Comment: the solution `gsub(pattern = "&gt;", replacement = ">", gsub(pattern = "&lt;", replacement = "<", x=print.xtable(xtable(DF,digits=2), type="html"), fixed = TRUE), fixed = TRUE)` works but is not very clean

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). It will make your solution more visible.

Comment: @Pascal I am ideally looking for a cleaner solution as this is just a quick fix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the default `sanitize.text.function` is changing the html tags. You can try to reset it to a function that does not change anything (setting it to `NULL` will call the default:

`print.xtable(xtable(DF,digits=2), type="html",sanitize.text.function=function(x){x})`